# Why don't I have debug.keystore in ~/.android folder(for mac)?

Tags: java, android, macos, keystore, keytool

`ls ~/.android`

> analytics.settings    avd/                cache/              metrics/

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/.android/debug.keystore java.lang.Exception:
>   Keystore file does not exist:
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/.android/debug.keystore     at
>   sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:745)     at
>   sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)    at
>   sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)

Answer (score 7):

There should be something wrong with your systems. But usually, the next time you build and run a debug version of your app, Android Studio will regenerates a new keystore and debug key for your. Read more details at [Expiry of Debug certificate](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#expdebug)

In case your Android Studio still not regenerate the debug key, you can use the following command:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**Keystore name**: `debug.keystore`
**Keystore password**: `android`
**Key alias**: `androiddebugkey`
**Key password**: `android`

Comment: I reliased the issue, I was expecting to find even before I had run Android Studio for the first time.

Comment: @ishandutta2007: Okay, I didn't suspect that at all.. Please mark this as accepted answer if it's satisfied your question. Or you can create your own answer then accept it.